# why is the order of kiddush different at night from the day?

Tags: minhag, shabbat, kiddush, meal-seudah

multiple parts to this question...

At night time why do we mention the wine before the day? It would seem most appropriate that after making the bracha on the wine there should be no interruption between the bracha and drinking the wine.

If there is a valid reason for allowing a hefsik at night why is the order reversed during the day time meal?

Comment: @Dude Instead of doing that why not just edit to clarify your question... The three parts of kiddush I see are 1) topical verses, 2) blessing on wine, 3) blessing on the day. During the day we omit 3. what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why this question wasn't answered earlier, but here goes.

The order of the two brachot (wine and day) on Friday night is an area of dispute between Beit Hillel and Beit Shammai in [Mishnah Brachot, chapter 8](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berakhot.8). Hillel says to do the wine first, Shammai says to do the day first. In the Gemarah ([Brachot, 51b](http://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.51b.65-67)) the rabbis explain that Hillel's logic was that the wine causes the holiness for which we say the bracha, while Shammai's logic was that the day caused the holiness.

The [gemarah also provides a second explanation](http://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.51b.69-70) that blessings over wine are said regularly, while the blessing for the day of shabbat is said less frequently, and the blessings which are more common always come first.

As is usually the case, the halacha follows Hillel.

As for the second part of your question on the daytime meal, I'm not sure exactly what you're referring to. Since we already blessed the day the previous night, there's no reason to say that blessing again. We recite a few psukim about the shabbat, then the blessing on the wine, then drink. ([source and more info at halachapedia](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Kiddush#Kiddish_of_the_day)).